# Wordpress - If 1st / 2nd / 3rd level custom page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type that is hierarchical.  I have 3 level of pages, I need a way to detect whether I am on the top level, 2nd level or 3rd level.  I've looked into this and can only find examples that work with is_page() but apparently that doesn't work with CPTs.

```
    function nldf_gallery() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'               => 'NLDF',
            'singular_name'      => 'NLDF',
            'add_new'            => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Add New NLDF',
            'edit_item'          => 'Edit NLDF',
            'new_item'           => 'New NLDF',
            'all_items'          => 'All NLDF',
            'view_item'          => 'View NLDF',
            'search_items'       => 'Search NLDF',
            'not_found'          => 'No NLDF found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No NLDF found in Trash',
            'menu_name'          => 'NLDF'
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'public'             => true,
            'hierarchical'       => true,
            'has_archive'        => false,
            'menu_position'      => 4,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
            'supports'           => array('title','editor','comments','revisions','page-attributes')
        );

        register_post_type('nldf', $args);

    }
    add_action('init', 'nldf_gallery');
```

Thanks!

Comment: OR - A way to use a different template for each level of pages

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Andy Macaulay-Brook from the wp stackexchange for the answer but wanted to post here incase anyone finds it.

```
$level = count( get_ancestors( get_queried_object_id(), 'nldf' ) );

add_filter('body_class','nldf_page_class_names');
function nldf_page_class_names($classes) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    $classes[] = 'single-nldf-' . $level;
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}

get_header( 'nldf-' . $level );
// loads header-nldf-0.php, header-nldf-1.php or header-nldf-2.php

get_template_part( 'loop', 'nldf-' . $level );
// loads loop-nldf-0.php, loop-nldf-1.php or loop-nldf-2.php

get_footer( 'nldf-' . $level );
// loads footer-nldf-0.php, footer-nldf-1.php or footer-nldf-2.php
```